# EntityFramework 6 with System.Data.Sqlite PK gets overriden on insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

I'm working on a project where I want to parse an xml-File into a sqlite database. Im having a problem where my ID value (in this case `TrackDataVersion`) gets overidden at the moment I insert it into the database.
I have the following Entity:

```
public class TrackData
{
    private int trackDataVersion;
    // many other variables

    public int TrackDataVersion { get => trackDataVersion; set => trackDataVersion = value; }
    // many other properties

    private void FillAttribute(XmlNode node)
    {
        string id = node.Attributes[1].InnerText;
        string value = node.Attributes[2].InnerText;
        switch (id)
        {
            case "stredatversion":
                int.TryParse(value, out trackDataVersion);
                break;
            //many other cases
        }
    }
```

In my `databaseContext` I set the `DatabaseGenereratedOption` with the fluent API to "NONE" so it should not be generated:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TrackData>()
            .HasKey(trackData => trackData.TrackDataVersion)
            .Property(trackData => trackData.TrackDataVersion)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
//other entities

var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<DatabaseContext>(modelBuilder);
        Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
```

(I also tried it with the annotation, but it didn't work either)

I have debugged the problem and until I insert the Entity into the database `TrackDataVersion` has the value 162 (my specified value). But when I check my database after the insert the value changed to 1.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I have the problem since I changed the datatype from `trackDataVersion` from double to int. Before that it worked fine, but it isn't the right datatype I want to use.